# Kitchen test how to use local vm.box

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

Every time I run

```
kitchen test
```

it downloads a new vm box. Is there a way to make it re-use a locally downloaded box?

Here is my .kitchen.yml file.

```
---
driver_plugin: vagrant
driver_config:
  require_chef_omnibus: true

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[my-rails-server::default]
    attributes:
```

Terminal output:

```
Downloading Chef  for ubuntu...       
downloading https://www.opscode.com/chef/metadata?v=&prerelease=false&p=ubuntu&pv=12.04&m=x86_64       
to file /tmp/install.sh.1121/metadata.txt       
trying wget...       
url https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/chef_11.10.0-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb       
md5 21524287ed5631eb1c092ba7b589e968       
sha256  7a0a898b3682462620de80230c7a73730dde7131ca069e1d926f6faf07e4fa2f       
downloaded metadata file looks valid...       
downloading https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/chef_11.10.0-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb       
to file /tmp/install.sh.1121/chef_11.10.0-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb       
trying wget...       
Checksum compare with sha256sum succeeded.       
Installing Chef
```

Comment: platforms:
    - name: ubuntu-12.04
    driver:
    box: ubuntu-12.04
    box_url: file:///home/user/doenloads/ubuntu-12.04.box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "downloads a new VM box", you mean destroys and creates one, yes, that's what `kitchen test` does. If you want to persist the instance, just run

```
kitchen converge
```

If you mean that Vagrant is downloading a new box from the Internet, then that's likely a bug in Vagrant.

Comment: Yes, Vagrant downloads a new box every time I run kitchen test.

Comment: That's downloading Chef, not the Ubuntu box

Answer (score 11):

Test Kitchen creates its own Vagrantfile, based on .kitchen.yml config.

Therefore you have to specify your box (which should be already available for Vagrant, check `vagrant box list`) in .kitchen.yml. In your example it would be:

```
platforms:
- name: ubuntu-12.04
  driver:
    box: centos-6.5-x86_64-minimal
```

And kitchen will use box available for Vagrant, without downloading it.

You can also specify other Vagrant options, e.g.

```
- name: centos-vagrant
  driver:
    provider: parallels
    box: centos-6.5-x86_64-minimal
    customize:
      memsize: 1024
      cpus: 2
```

You can see more examples eg. in my Vagrant cookbooks [lemp-server](https://github.com/ryzy/vc-lemp-server) or or Opscode's [yum](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum).

Comment: Thanks marcin-r it was the driver/box line that I was missing

Comment: The OP updated the original question, but that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
exec kitchen converge ubuntu
```

converge will regex of instances

Answer (score 0):

Use the following definition in your kitchen.yml to disable box updates

```
platforms:
  - name: centos-7
    driver:
      box: bento/centos-7
      box_check_update: false
```

where the box is a locally available vagrant box in your host. Run the following command to get a list of available boxes:

```
$ vagrant box list
bento/centos-6.7           (virtualbox, 2.2.7)
bento/centos-7             (virtualbox, 201808.24.0)
```